# Error in for loop. (Finding three integers)

Tags: python, for-loop

So, our teacher gave us an assignment to find three integers a, b c. They are in all between 0 and 450 using Python.

a = c + 11 if b is even
a = 2c-129 if b is odd

b = ac mod 2377

c = (∑(b-7k) from k = 0 too a-1) +142 (Edited. I wrote it wrong. Was -149)

I tired my code that looks like this: (Still a newbie. I guess a lot of my code is wrong)

```
for a, b, c in range(0, 450):
    if b % 2 == 0:
        a = c + 11
    else:
        a = 2 * c - 129
    b = (a * c) % 2377
    c = sum(b - 7 * k for k in range(0, a - 1))
```

but I get the error:

```
for a, b, c in range(0, 450):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make it check every number between 0 and 450?

Comment: What do you expect it to do in this case?

Comment: range(0,450) gives you a single number, not 3 at once. I think you need to iterate on 1 value (probably a) and verify the value for the 2 others.

Comment: What @njzk2 said. There are more than 91 million combinations of numbers in the range 0..450. That's a lot to test especially as calculating `c` involves another loop. Best just to iterate one number over the range and calculate the other two from it then check that all are in the required range and that the calculated value for the third matches the number you started with. That's 451 loops instead of 91 million.

Comment: BTW, your calculation of `c` has two mistakes in it: the `range` parameters are wrong, and you forgot to add `142`. I'd hate for you find that after the brute force method. The solution I wrote (but I won't spoil it for you) took 96 milliseconds to find the unique solution, so there's a target for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

for b, c in itertools.product(*[range(450)]*2):
    if b % 2 == 0:
        a = c + 11
    else:
        a = 2 * c - 129
    derived_b = (a * c) % 2377
    derived_c = sum(b - 7 * k for k in range(0, a - 1))

    if derived_b == b and derived_c == c:
        print a, b, c
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers by Nick T and Eric hopefully helped you solve your issue with iterating over values of `a`, `b`, and `c`. I would like to also point out that the way you're approaching this problem isn't going to work. What's the point of iterating over various values of `a` if you're going to re-assign `a` to something anyway at each iteration of the loop? And likewise for `b` and `c`. A better approach involves *checking* that any given triple `(a, b, c)` *satisfies* the conditions given in the assignment. For example:

```
from itertools import product, tee

def test(a, b, c):
    flags = {'a': False,
             'b': False,
             'c': False}
    if (b % 2 == 0 and a == c+11) or (b % 2 == 1 and a == 2*c-129):
        flags['a'] = True
    if b == (a * c) % 2377:
        flags['b'] = True
    if c == sum(b - 7*k for k in range(a-1)) - 149:
        flags['c'] = True
    return all(flags.values()) # True if zero flags are False

def run_tests():
    # iterate over all combinations of a=0..450, b=0..450, c=0..450
    for a, b, c in product(*tee(range(451), 3)):
        if test(a, b, c):
            return (a, b, c)

print(run_tests())
```

**NOTE:** This is a slow solution. One that does fewer loops, like in glglgl's answer, or Duncan's comment, is obviously favorable. This is really more for illustrative purposes than anything.

Comment: What is "product" and "tee"?

Comment: @Zahand See the [relevant documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to nest the loops to brute-force it like you are attempting:

```
for a in range(451): # range(450) excludes 450
    for b in range(451):
        for c in range(451):
            ...
```

It's very obviously O(n<sup>3</sup>), but if you want a quick and dirty answer, I guess it'll work—only 91 million loops, worst case.

Comment: More than 91 million: remember that calculating the correct value for `c` invoves on average 225 iterations. So that's 21 thousand million times round that particular loop unless some of the loops are skipped.

Comment: Ah, so no brute forcing.  The formatting on the equations was a bit muddy so I just glazed over that to the "why can't I unpack 3 numbers from 1 number" problem.

Comment: nˆ4 actually because of the computation of c

Answer (score 1):

The stuff with [0, 450] is just as a hint.

In fact, your variables are coupled together. You can immediately eliminate at least one loop directly:

```
for b in range(0, 451):
    for c in range(0, 451):
        if b % 2: # odd
            a = 2 * c - 129
        else:
            a = c + 11
        if b != (a * c) % 2377: continue # test failed
        if c != sum(b - 7 * k for k in range(a)): continue # test failed as well
        print a, b, c
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I won't post full code (after all, it is homework), but you can eliminate two of the outer loops. This is easiest if you iterate over `c`.

You code should then look something like:

```
 for c in range(451):
     # calculate a assuming b is even
     # calculate b
     # if b is even and a and b are in range:
        # calculate what c should be and compare against what it is
     # calculate a assuming b is odd
     # calculate b
     # if b is odd and a and b are in range:
        # calculate what c should be and compare against what it is
```

Extra credit for eliminating the duplication of the code to calculate `c`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = c + 11 if b is even
a = 2c-129 if b is odd
b = ac mod 2377

c = (∑(b-7k) from k = 0 to a-1) +142
```

This gives you a strong relation between all 3 numbers

Given a value `a`, there are 2 values `c` (`a-11` or `(a+129)/2`), which in turn give 2 values for b (`ac mod 2377` for both values of c, conditioned on the oddity of the result for b), which in turn gets applied in the formula for validating c.

The overall complexity for this is o(n^2) because of the formula to compute c.

Here is an implementation example:

```
for a in xrange(451):
    c_even = a - 11
    b = (a*c_even) % 2377
    if b % 2 == 0:
        c = sum(b - 7 * k for k in range(a)) + 142
        if c == c_even:
            print (a, b, c)
            break
    c_odd = (a+129)/2
    b = (a*c_odd) % 2377
    if b % 2 == 1:
        c = sum(b - 7 * k for k in range(a)) + 142
        if c == c_odd:
            print (a, b, c)
            break
```